# Find $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\frac9{1-x^9}-\frac7{1-x^7}$ without using L'Hopital

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac9{1-x^9}-\frac7{1-x^7}$$

I did this with l'Hôpital's rule, but how can we do this problem other than that? Any hints will be good.

Comment: $1-x^n = (1-x)\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^i$ is another way to go

Comment: Let $x=1+t$ then $t\to0$ when $x\to1$ hence $$1-x^9=1-(1+t)^9=-9t-36t^2+o(t^2)$$ and $$1-x^7=1-(1+t)^7=-7t-21t^2+o(t^2)$$ which leads to $$f(x)=\frac{9}{1-x^9}-\frac{7}{1-x^7}=-\frac1{t+4t^2+o(t^2)}-\frac1{t+3t^2+o(t^2)}$$ that is, $$f(x)=\frac1t\left(\frac1{1+4t+o(t)}-\frac1{1+3t+o(t)}\right)$$ and finally, $$f(x)=\frac1t\left(1-4t-(1-3t)+o(t)\right)=-1+o(1)$$

Comment: Or: $$2-9x^7+7x^9=(1-x)^2(2+4x+6x^2+8x^3+10x^4+12x^5+14x^6+7x^7)\sim63(1-x)^2$$

Comment: For the record, I forgot a minus sign in the "that is" step of my first comment hence the limit is $+1$, not $-1$.

Comment: @Did: If I were you, I'd write up your comments as an answer, so you can edit it however you want.

Comment: And finally, the same approach yields, for every $(a,b)$, $$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{a}{1-x^a}-\frac{b}{1-x^b}=\frac{a-b}2$$

Comment: @Did thanks got it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference of fractions equals $\frac{9(1-x^7) - 7(1-x^9)}{(1-x^7)(1-x^9)}$.

Try to divide out the common $(1-x)^2$ terms in both the bottom and the top.

In the bottom we get $(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^8)(1+x + x^2 + \ldots + x^6)$

In the top $7x^7 + 14x^6 + 12x^5 + 10x^4 + 8x^3 + 6x^2 + 4x + 2$ (multiply by $(1-x)^2$ to check both). Now we can just substitute $x=1$ in both. I get 63 twice OTTOMH.

Comment: I tried this already, turns out 1 $1-x$ term disturbs the whole thing

Comment: @user354545 Factoring $(1-x)^2$ in the numerator and the denominator works like a charm.

Comment: @Did ,sorry but  im not getting it

Comment: @user354545 Cannot you factor $(1-x)^2$ in $(1-x^7)(1-x^9)$?

Comment: Oh, so you are using binomial, i get it. Havent done binomial in detail yet

Comment: @user354545 it's not the binomial, just long division that you can let [Wolfram](http://wolframalpha.com) do for you, if you're lazy.

Comment: But i wont get this much time in exam right? There must be better ways, anyhow, your efforts are appreciated :)

Comment: @user354545 the first is a geometric series one should know by heart, the second is 5 minutes work on paper, 10 tops..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{9}{1-x^9}-\frac{7}{1-x^7}$$

Set $x=1-y$

$$\dfrac9{1-x^9}-\dfrac7{1-x^7}=\cdots=\dfrac1{y-4y^2+O(y^3)}-\dfrac1{y-3y^2+O(y^3)}=?$$

Comment: I dont know taylor series or whatever series that is :(

Comment: @user354545, I have used http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialTheorem.html

Comment: lab bhattacharjee can we chat pls